# Pool with MySQL and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a web application with ASP.NET and MySQL, but I am not using the SqlClient provider.

I read somewhere (I do not remember where) that if I need to establish a connection pool I need to add some lines to file `web.config`.

To make a connection, defined in each model there is a connection string, something like:

```
string sqlConnection = 
    "server=localhost; user id=root; password=***; database=test; pooling=true;Min Pool Size=0; Max Pool Size=60;";
```

And to connect and do query I do the following:

```
MySqlConnection conection;
conection = new MySqlConnection(sqlConnection);
string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM documents WHERE user_id = ?user_id;
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conection);`

cmd.Connection.Open();
cmd.Prepare();
cmd.Parameters.Add("?user_id", userID);
cmd.ExecuteReader();
...
cmd.Connection.Close();
```

But I want to open a connection pool and use pooled connections, I do not want to open and close a connection every time.

I put this in the `web.config` file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalMySqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalMySqlServer" 
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost; userid=root;  password=***; database=test; Pooling=true; Min Pool Size=50; Max Pool Size=100;"  
         providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But when I start the development server, I do not see any connections in [MySQL Workbench](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench).

This only happens when I call the model and open a connection.

What is the way to have connection pooling at startup time?

Comment: So are you able to connect and query the database using the connection string in web.config?

Comment: Thomas Li, no, I don't know how to do that, actually I defined the connection string on each model, but I think that this is not the correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the concept of connection pooling.

Connection pooling is a mechanism provided by the database driver or provider. You still have to ask for a connection but instead of the driver/provider creating a whole new connection each time you create a connection, it maintains a pool of ready made warmed up objects and hands you one of them.

This all happens silently under the covers.

**Update:**

To consume a connection string from your `web.config`:

```
string sqlConnection = 
   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalMySqlServer"].ConnectionString;
```

You might have to add a reference to `System.Configuration`:

[image]

And add a:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

To the top of your class file.

That's for a .NET 4.0 project, but the principle is the same with .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change Min Pool Size=0 to something larger. This should ensure that always X number of connections are available in the pool.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalMySqlServer"]`